# ElasticSearch _reindex yields "no such index"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two instances of the same version of elasticsearch with the same data.

I am now trying to `_reindex` an index with:

```bash
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/_reindex' -d '{"source": {"index": "my_index_v1"}, "dest": { "index": "my_index_v2" }}'  | jq
```

On one of the machines, it works correctly and a new index is correctly created. However on second machine, it ends with:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index [my_index_v2] and [action.auto_create_index] ([.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*,.monitoring-*]) doesn't match",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "my_index_v2"
      }
    ],
    "type": "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason": "no such index [my_index_v2] and [action.auto_create_index] ([.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*,.monitoring-*]) doesn't match",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "my_index_v2"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

I checked the `elasticsearch.yml` and the file is completely equal on both machines and contains following:

```
action.auto_create_index: .watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*,.monitoring-*
```

I have no idea why this happens.

To be clear, the index really exists.

EDIT:

1. working machine

   - elastic version: 7.17.4
   - settings.json: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/90f5d0f5de194be534160ab729c5a83b
2. non-working machine

   - elastic version: 7.17.4
   - settings.json: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/fcb94cd5739d3626f4545a9b9c5cceef

From the diff it seems that the working machine contains also:

```json
{
  "persistent": {
    "action": {
      "auto_create_index": "true"
    },
    …
  }
}
```

So I guess that can be the culprit.

Comment: localhost:9200 work when you try to reach it using a navigator? Did you try with IP 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Ofcourse, that works correctly. I can also try this with Kibana with the same result. The isntance response normally apart from this query.

Comment: This is strange what happens if you add my_index_* behind the action.auto_create_index (restart es). Or if you create the index my_index_v2 manually.

Comment: Well it is strange, that is why I created this question :) I want to understand the problem.

Comment: From my understanding this would be the expected behaviour **IF** the index did not exist.
I think the investigation should go down this road. Could you do a `GET /my_index_v2` on the machine that throw this error ?

Comment: Of course, the target (new) index does not exist yet. However I don't understand why it is nicely created on the other machine. As I said, the `auto_create_index` list is same on both machines.

Comment: Then , what does "To be clear, the index really exists." means ?

Comment: Could you check `GET /_cluster/settings?include_defaults=true` and make sure the settings are the same ? Those settings can be updated without a restart.

Comment: What version of elastic are you running ?

Comment: I updated the question with the your questions. The `/_cluster/settings` seems to lead somewhere as it says `"auto_create_index": "true"`. I guess that might be it, will try.

Comment: Okay, this helped, if you post it as an aswer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update ***auto_create_index*** in second machine as,

```
{
    "persistent": {
      "action": {
        "auto_create_index": "true"
      }
    }
}
```

instead of

```
action.auto_create_index: .watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*,.monitoring-*
```

could likely fix the issue.